# how can we put new input values into another element?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-web-developer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5h1V.jpg)

I have an input element. I take input values into an element. But i want new input values to put into next element ? i hope someone will help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this.

We have **input1** and **input2**

In case you want to put the **input1** value into **input2** you have to request it and then set it

```js
function setValues(){
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
document.getElementById("input2").value = input1;
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
<button id="button" onclick="setValues()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: thanks bro for help. if you check the picture you will see all input tasks appear in first card. i can't put new input values into second card

Comment: Post in a new answer the code so i can help you

Comment: https://wercan.github.io/toDoApp/    here how it does look like